# The Tesseract OCR engine isn't able to read the text from an auto generated image, but can from a CUT in MS Paint

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, ocr, tesseract

I'm using a .NET wrapper for the Tesseract OCR engine. I have a large document that is a PNG. When I cut out a section of image in MS paint and then feed it into the engine, it works. But when I do it in code, the engine can't recognize the text in the image. The images look the same and the properties don't appear very off. So I'm a little confused.

Here are the two images. From MS paint:

[image]

From code:

[image]

This is what I get from the MS paint image:

[image]

And through code:

[image]

They're really similar So I'm not sure why it can't recognize the second text. The following is how I'm generating the image.

```
public Bitmap CropImage(Bitmap source, Rectangle section)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(section.Width, section.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, section, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        return bmp;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap source = new Bitmap(test);
        Rectangle section = new Rectangle(new Point(78, 65), new Size(800, 50));
        Bitmap CroppedImage = CropImage(source, section);
        CroppedImage.Save(@"c:\users\user\desktop\test34.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        this.pictureBox1.Image = CroppedImage;
    }
```

Comment: could you show the code where you are calling Tesseract? it could be that the Tesseract ocr is executing correctly from the command line, but not when called by the wrapper.

Comment: @AruniRC [Here's](http://pastebin.com/Z6tLah6M) the code. I haven't changed much of anything from the demo project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default resolution of a new Bitmap is 96 DPI, which is not adequate for OCR purpose. Try to increase to 300 DPI, such as:

`bmp.SetResolution(300, 300);`

Update 1: When you scale the image, its dimension should change as well. Here's an example rescale function:

```
public static Image Rescale(Image image, int dpiX, int dpiY)
{
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap((int)(image.Width * dpiX / image.HorizontalResolution), (int)(image.Height * dpiY / image.VerticalResolution));
    bm.SetResolution(dpiX, dpiY);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Bicubic;
    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
    g.Dispose();

    return bm;
}
```

Comment: Hm... is there any specific way I need to change the resolution? I called SetResolution and then saved the image. However, the file appears the same. Same size and everything. I even tried changing it to (1000, 1000). The OCR engine still couldn't recognize it. I don't think it changed the bitmap at all.

Comment: Wrapping `test` image in a new Bitmap also changes the resolution to 96 DPI.

Comment: So, I got it to reflect changes in the image. However, as I increase the number, the image gets smaller. So I went in reverse and lowered it from 96.0F to 80.0F and then 50.0F. Nothing was recognized.