# About tessnet2 OCR font size

Tags: .net, ocr, tessnet2

I have a PNG image.The font size is 10

But tessnet2 can not get the text.If change the font size to 16 ,it work well!

How to fix it?Thanks!

Comment: Get better quality (higher resolution) images...

Comment: Try to increase the image resolution, e.g., [rescaling][1] it to 300 DPI.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638861/the-tesseract-ocr-engine-isnt-able-to-read-the-text-from-an-auto-generated-imag