# Read text from screenshot

Tags: c#, selenium, tesseract

I'm using selenium to go to `x` website and take screenshot

```
public static void TakeScreenshot(IWebDriver driver, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
         var name =
            $@"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)}\{"screenshots"}\{Guid.NewGuid()}.{
                ScreenshotImageFormat.Png
            }";

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

        Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
        var bitmapScreen = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(screenshot.AsByteArray));
        var croppedArea = new Rectangle(rect.Location, rect.Size);

        bitmapScreen.Clone(croppedArea, bitmapScreen.PixelFormat).Save(name);
    }
```

and after saving that I'm trying to read text from that image using [tesseract](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract/)

```
var testImagePath = @".\Content\300.png";
var dataPath = @".\tessdata";

        try
        {
            using (var tEngine = new TesseractEngine(dataPath, "eng", EngineMode.Default)) //creating the tesseract OCR engine with English as the language
            {
                using (var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(testImagePath)) // Load of the image file from the Pix object which is a wrapper for Leptonica PIX structure
                {
                    using (var page = tEngine.Process(img)) //process the specified image
                    {
                        var text = page.GetText(); //Gets the image's content as plain text.
                        Console.WriteLine(text); //display the text
                        Console.WriteLine(page.GetMeanConfidence()); //Get's the mean confidence that as a percentage of the recognized text.
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected Error: " + e.Message);
        }
```

but I'm getting that dummy text:

[image]

so I tried to rescale that image

```
bitmapScreen.SetResolution(300, 300);
```

as I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639160/3801087)

but result is the same

Comment: what's the original image you're trying to read text from?

Comment: @Kirhgoph here it is: http://imgur.com/a/dYiZj

Comment: Are you sure that this text is not visible in the source code of the Web page? why is the website's address in your question "x"?

Comment: yeah because it's flash web page. it's hard to go there (not international website, + it needs authorization etc.)

Comment: uploaded your image there: http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/ and got similar dummy text. looks like "Tesseract" in not helpful here

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
private static Bitmap CaptureScreen()
{
    Rectangle screenSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    var screenCapture = new Bitmap(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenCapture))
    {
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(screenSize.X, screenSize.Y, 0, 0, screenSize.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    }

    return screenCapture;
}

private static byte[] BitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}

private void ReadEntireScreen()
{
    Bitmap screenshot = CaptureScreen();

    using (var ocrEngine = new TesseractEngine(@"D:\Projects\tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
    {
        var kelle = BitmapToByteArray(screenshot);
        using (var pix = Pix.LoadFromMemory(kelle))
        {
            using (var page = ocrEngine.Process(pix))
            {

                string recognizedText = page.GetText();

                Console.WriteLine("Text:");
                Console.WriteLine(recognizedText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can use TryGetBoundingBox for separate text blocks with
`PageIteratorLevel.Word`, `PageIteratorLevel.TextLine` or `PageIteratorLevel.Block`

```
do
{
    if (iter.TryGetBoundingBox(PageIteratorLevel.Word, out var boundingBox))
    {
        string wordText = iter.GetText(PageIteratorLevel.Word);

        Console.WriteLine($"Word: {wordText}, Coords: ({boundingBox.X1}, {boundingBox.Y1}, {boundingBox.X2}, {boundingBox.Y2})");
    }
} while (iter.Next(PageIteratorLevel.Word));
```